# Using 'will' vs. 'would' in this sentence

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, tenses, aspect

I'd like to know which one of the following is correct:

> - I would like to have a job which I **will** like and which **will** earn me a lot of money.
> - I would like to have a job which I **would** like and which **would** earn me a lot of money.

My guess is it's the second one, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Lukas, questions are expected to show considerable evidence of research and be of interest to language experts (professionals and enthusiastic amateurs). However you may be interested in our new proposal specifically tailored for those who want to learn the English language: English Language Learners (ell.stackexchange.com). On EL&U this kind of questions are considered too basic at best and not constructive at worst, but on ELL they are welcome. Please, take a look now or, at any rate, be aware that that proposal exists. Thank you.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: OK, please accept my newbie apologize. I'll take ELL at account. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd use *that* instead of at least the first *which*, but that's really just a stylistic choice.

And there's no reason to cast *like* or *earn* as future/conditional. More natural phrasing would be...

> "I would like to have a job that I like, and which earns me a lot of money."

Comment: Fumble, please, don't answer to too basic questions. Rather, if any, invite the asker to create an account on ELL. Otherwise, we will never see ELL in the standard phase. Thank you.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: I'm not sure how "basic" the underlying issue here is. I can't explain exactly why neither of the verbs *like* and *earn* need to be future tense in my rephrasing, even though both clearly refer to future activities. And I *certainly* can't explain why it would be very unnatural to use future tense for *like*, even though there'd be nothing particularly unusual about ***will** earn* there.

Answer (score 0):

This is extracted from a news report from the Guardian. The use of “would” in
this context does not seem to have been covered by any grammar book. It is not
future in the past. It is not conditional. It does not look like hedging or
tentative which usually appears in the forms of “it would appear” or “it would
seem that” any one has any idea?

Now the proposed law “would” provide a legal framework that “would” make
domestic abuse a specific offence and “would” allow for the examination of an
offender's course of conduct over a period of time. Supporters say this “would”
encourage more women to report a crime that is often neglected by the criminal
justice system, sometimes with tragic consequences. Research shows that the
average victim does not report abuse until subjected to at least 30 incidents.
Only 30% of reports to police result in arrest and only one in six reports lead
to a charge.

The law “would” see domestic abuse categorised as both physical and
psychological and perpetrated against the victim or the victim's children. It
“would” define abuse as "intentionally, wilfully or recklessly causing, or
attempting to cause, physical injury or psychological harm to a person"
and introduce protective orders prohibiting an abuser from making contact with
their victim.